# Laravel Maatwebsite how many columns its will accept?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, import-from-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I am doing bulk import using the Laravel Maatwebsite, I Want to Know the how many columns its will accept. Max capability of Maatwebsite excel import.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a hard coded limit other than the max columns in an Excel file, 16 384.

What I can say is that I often import a file with more than 150 columns (200 000 rows) and it works.

The main problem is the performance, it can quickly become a pain.

For a file with 10 rows and 3 columns, you have 30 cells, add a column and you have 40 cells.

Each column you add will have a performance hit.